# Spring MVC+Spring boot + Security Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Добрый день. Пытаюсь собрать проэкт Spring MVC+Spring boot+Security, при запуске выскакивает:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in class path resource [ua/kiev/izodrom/egorov/configuration/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]: Factory method 'multipartResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
```

WEB:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.register(SecurityConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите весь стектрейс, вдруг там чего есть :) Если он в open source, то дайте ссылку на github.

Answer (score 1):

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Похоже на какие-то проблемы с отсутствием `commons-fileupload` либо его неправильной версией.

См.также:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166898/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileitemfactory
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154252/how-to-solve-this-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-io-output-d

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>    Я с это и начал с проблемой разбираться)

Comment: Покажите вывод комманд `mvn dependency:tree | grep commons` и `jar tvf target/you-app.jar | grep commons`

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'dependecy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Nikol\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: package:     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my: Could not resolve dependencies for project ua.kiev.izodrom.egoov:my:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.el:el-api:jar:${el-impl.version} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: `dependency` != `dependecy`

Comment: mvn dependency:tree BUILD SUCCESS, mvn package BUILD SUCCESS Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Это не то, что мы ищем. Если вы под виндой, то используйте `findstr` (или другую эквивалентную команду) вместо `grep`. Нужно проверить, что `commons-fileupload` попадает в результирующий JAR.

Comment: commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile  Это оно?

Comment: Возможно, что проблема именно в том, что подключаете вы версию 1.3.2, а реально используется 1.2.1

Comment: Это ничего не говорит?    [WARNING] The POM for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:${servlet-api.version} is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for javax.el:el-api:jar:${el-impl.version} is missing, no dependency information available   Версия fileupload 1.2 у меня....Я менял....Сейчас так \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.2:compile и в dependency тоже

Comment: Внутри JAR-файла точно версия 1.3.2? Как запускаете -- как `java -jar` или деплоите на какой-нибудь сервер (где тоже может быть этот артефакт)? Ну и предупреждение исправьте, авось поможет :)

Comment: Spring boot Tomcat...